# Does Cap.read() skip frames in camera stream but not when running from file?

Tags: python, opencv

i noticed a behaviour that i didn't find an answer for in the [documentation](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html).

when I capture a stream from camera using VideoCapture(0), *check code below* I noticed that some frames are skipped because of the delay I put in the code.

but when I playback a video, it doesn't skip the frames.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#cap = cv2.VideoCapture("awesomevideo.mp4")     
while True :
    # Get a new frame from camera
    retval, frame = cap.read()
    time.sleep(1)
    # Display images
    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
```

am I understanding this behaviour correctly, or it's an issue with my code?
this is just a test script of course, i noticed the issue when i was working with a stream from the camera,my while loop would take 0.4s then it would grab the next frame (it skips few in between) , but when I saved the same video and decided to do offline processing , i noticed it doesn't skip frames, ie, it justs waits until i finish processing the frame to give me the next, not like the camera which just grabs whatever the camera is displaying now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot obtain all the frames from the real world. The frame rate would be infinite, which is impossible. The camera tries to capture as many frames as possible, in the limits of capture duration and processing time. By adding `sleep`, you increase the processing time.

A recorded video has discrete samples of frames from the real world, which is sufficient for us to perceive the stream as if it flows infinitely. Human eye captures 24 frames per second. If the purpose of the video was to use it for birds, the frame rate should be at least 80.

Having known these, it should be clear why `VideoCapture` behaves like you said. The camera tries to capture as many frames as possible from the real world. As for a recorded video, you already have all the frames.

As a footnote, you should use `cv2.waitKey(1)` instead of `time.sleep(1)` after `imshow` for displaying purposes. See documentation of [`imshow`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.11/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga453d42fe4cb60e5723281a89973ee563).